# wifi-direct end connection to peer on Android?

Tags: android, wifi-direct, service-discovery

Is there any way to end the connection to a peer over Wifi-Direct?
I tried cancelConnect and removeGroup. Both of them returned Busy? thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the method I am using to disconnect from peer. I noticed from logs that the android built in app also uses the same method to disconnect the peers.

```
public static void disconnect() {
    if (mManager != null && mChannel != null) {
        mManager.requestGroupInfo(mChannel, new GroupInfoListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupInfoAvailable(WifiP2pGroup group) {
                if (group != null && mManager != null && mChannel != null) {
                    mManager.removeGroup(mChannel, new ActionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            Log.d(TAG, "removeGroup onSuccess -");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int reason) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "removeGroup onFailure -" + reason);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Edit 1/12/2020: Removed isGroupOwner() from the if-statement. This allows a non-owner device to disconnect using this same method.

When a non-owner disconnects, the new WifiP2pInfo will show:

`groupFormed: false isGroupOwner: false groupOwnerAddress: null`

You can find your WifiP2pInfo from:

(1) Registering a broadcast receiver listening to `WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION` and getting WifiP2pInfo from the extra `EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_INFO`

(2) By calling `WifiP2pManager#requestConnectionInfo`

Comment: Is there a way to disconnect if you are not the group owner?